# Bootstrap - space between columns and aligning bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

AS you may see on my image the third one has more padding down then the others because of bigger text.

1. How to get them to all 3 of them to align the same at bottom.
2. How to make more space between those 3 columns in desktop view?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio_wrapper" >
    <div class="thumbnail_portfolio text-center"> <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/design-or-die-zidna-naljepnica/" title="Design or die zidna naljepnica"> <img src="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/zid1-270x270.jpg" width="270"  height="270" alt="" class="" /> </a> </div>
    <div class="item_title"> <a href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/design-or-die-zidna-naljepnica/" rel="bookmark" style="font-weight:bold;">Design or die zidna naljepnica</a>
      <div><span style="color:#bab5b5;">Kategorija: </span> <span>Print</span> <span style="color:#ce003d;">/</span> <span style="color:#bab5b5;">Godina: </span> <span></span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- .item_title --> 

    <!-- .entry --> 

  </div>
  <!-- .portfolio_content -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio_wrapper" >
    <div class="thumbnail_portfolio text-center"> <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/hypo-mudro-uokvirena-stednja/" title="Hypo mudro uokvirena štednja"> <img src="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/32-270x270.jpg" width="270"  height="270" alt="" class="" /> </a> </div>
    <div class="item_title"> <a href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/hypo-mudro-uokvirena-stednja/" rel="bookmark" style="font-weight:bold;">Hypo mudro uokvirena štednja</a>
      <div><span style="color:#bab5b5;">Kategorija: </span> <span>Video/animacija</span> <span style="color:#ce003d;">/</span> <span style="color:#bab5b5;">Godina: </span> <span></span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- .item_title --> 

    <!-- .entry --> 

  </div>
  <!-- .portfolio_content -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio_wrapper" >
    <div class="thumbnail_portfolio text-center"> <a rel="bookmark" href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/stare-razglednice-slavonskih-sela-i-gradova/" title="Stare razglednice slavonskih sela i gradova"> <img src="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/razglednice3-270x270.jpg" width="270"  height="270" alt="" class="" /> </a> </div>
    <div class="item_title"> <a href="http://www.pippion.com/wordpress/portfolio/stare-razglednice-slavonskih-sela-i-gradova/" rel="bookmark" style="font-weight:bold;">Stare razglednice slavonskih sela i gradova</a>
      <div><span style="color:#bab5b5;">Kategorija: </span> <span>Print</span> <span style="color:#ce003d;">/</span> <span style="color:#bab5b5;">Godina: </span> <span></span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- .item_title --> 

    <!-- .entry --> 

  </div>
  <!-- .portfolio_content --> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not the padding but your text that causes that.

On the 3rd image the text takes 3 lines instead of 2 for the 2 other images.

Try to reduce the size of your text and it will work.

Comment: I worked it out. Text supposed to be 14-15px so I had to find another solution

Comment: Add min-height on your block that handle image and text height height.